# Rails 3: command used to return a number now returns "nil can't be coerced into Fixnum"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, fixnum

```
<%= msg.average_rating %>
```

used to return either NaN or a number: NaN if the `msg` had recieved no ratings or the average of all the ratings the message had recieved. But now it returns `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`. I must have done something to break the code but I have no idea what. What is `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum` and how do I fix it?

```
  def average_rating
      @value = 0
      self.ratings.each do |rating|
          @value = @value + rating.value
      end
      @total = self.ratings.size
      @value.to_f / @total.to_f
  end
```

Comment: What is `msg` (what Ruby class is it), and what does the implemantation of `average_rating` look like?

Comment: `def average_rating
      @value = 0
      self.ratings.each do |rating|
          @value = @value + rating.value
      end
      @total = self.ratings.size
      @value.to_f / @total.to_f
  end`

Comment: I'm fairly new to rails so what do you mean by "what ruby class is it"?

Comment: Most methods are implemented inside a class. So you have `class Something; def average_rating; ... end; end`. So that means `msg` will probably be an instance of this `Something` class, which probably is a Rails model in your app or something similar like an `Array`. That's what you mean when you ask for the class of a variable. If you'd type `puts msg.class` then ruby would print it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that `rating.value` is `nil` for some `rating`. Nothing else in your `average_rating` would produce that error.

You could try this:

```
self.ratings.each do |rating|
    @value = @value + rating.value.to_i
end
```

Calling `nil.to_i` gives you a zero whereas calling `x.to_i` for any Fixnum `x` gives you just `x`. You should also figure out why `rating.value` is giving you a `nil` when it probably shouldn't.

Also, you could use [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) instead of `each`:

```
@value = self.ratings.inject(0) { |sum, rating| sum += rating.value.to_i }
```

but that doesn't solve your `nil` problem, just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

The nil problem is caused because in your controller you build a rating:

```
@rating = @someobject.ratings.build
```

So from your db:

```
@someobject.ratings.count = x
```

while in your controller after calling the build, you have

```
@someobject.ratings.count = x+1
```

with parameters

```
#<Rating id: nil, user_id: nil, category_id: 2, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

where it's value=nil.

So you can either assign average_rating to a variable before you call the build and use that in your view, use the to_i method to zero the nil, or use the sum method on the array, which will handle the nil for you.

Hope that helps......like a year later. :-)